# Django REST Framework client.login() not working. (User created)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-tests, django-rest-auth

I'm building simple API with Django REST Framework, everything works as expected with curl and API web admin, but if I run the following test:

```
class OrderTest(APITestCase):
    username = 'admin'
    password = '12345'

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create(
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            email='demo@demo.com',
            is_superuser=True,
            is_staff=True
        )

    def test_create_order_by_admin(self):
        url = '/api/orders/'
        data = {
            'name': 'John Doe',
            'phone': '380000000000',
            'status': 1,
            'email': 'jonhn.doe@gmail.com',
            'date': datetime.now(),
        }
        # Cheking if user exist
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.get(pk=1).username, self.username)
        self.client.login(
            username=self.username,
            password=self.password,
        )
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(Order.objects.count(), 1)

        for key, value in data.items():
            self.assertEqual(Order.objects.get().key, value)
```

it fails with the following error:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linevich/projects/swebion.com/project/order_form/tests.py", line 71, in test_create_order_by_admin
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 403 != 201
```

That means that `client.login()` not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: What was the return value of `self.client.login` ?

Comment: btw this is not related to your problem, but I recommend to remove the first assert (the one about the username) because that is not what you are testing here.  Just save the `self.user = User(...)` in the setUp method.

Comment: User.objects.create_user(['user', 'mail@example.com', 'password'])

Comment: @C14L I set create_superuser and it works for me, write this as answer. Thank you!

Comment: @wim thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in using `User.objects.create()` insetad of `User.objects.create_superuser()`, thanks to [@C14L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5520354/c14l).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set the password directly. This will store password in clear text while Django will try a hashing algorithm when trying to login.
See [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) to store it encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Use ***authenticate*** function in place of **client.login**

Here i use generic class based view to login user..

class Login(generics.CreateAPIView):
        '''
        API for SignIn to return User models along with access token.
        '''

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.request.data.get('email', None)
        password = self.request.data.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        response = {}
        if user:
            access = AppCustomMethods()
            access_token = access.create_access_token(user, request,
                                                      settings.XAMARIN_APPLICATION_NAME)
            response_data = {}
            response_data['access_token'] = access_token
            signup_serializer = serializers.GetUserWithAllBusinesses(user)
            response_data[settings.USER] = signup_serializer.data
            response = GetAccesUtility.data_wrapper(response_data)
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            response['error'] = Messages.NOT_AUTHENTICATED  # error_data
            response["status_code"] = settings.HTTP_USER_ERROR
            return Response(response)
```

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

Django **authenticate** function authenticate the user username or password and return user info. If it return user then a new **access token** is generated and return in response with status 200 else if user not return by authenticated function then error message return in response.

Comment: Actually problem was in using `User.objects.create()` insetad of `User.objects.create_superuser()`, but thanks for advice!